# How many ways is there to partition a set of N elements?

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking about the following problem, typically a combinatorics one.

Imagine that we have a set of N elements.
I want to divide this set into K subsets. Each subset contains a varying number of elements.
K is a natural number strictly higher than 1.

The question is : how many ways is there to make K subsets from my original set of N elements ?

Exemple : for a set with 4 elements, I know that there are  $ 1/2 \sum_{p=1}^{4-1} \binom{n}{p} = 7 $ ways of making 2 subsets.

Thanks !!

Christophe

Comment: [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Perfect ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !!